# configure Java EE application for JavaScript Not enabled error

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

Is there any way to configure my web aaplication in Java EE so that if JavaScript is not enabled, it always opens a error page.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<noscript>` tag to show message or link that javascript is not enabled.
However its always a best practice to make functionality with graceful degradation.

Try this

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/error" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: This one, I will have to apply this tag to every page, Is there any way to do it globally, like defining in web.xml

Comment: JavaScript is client side so it cannot be determined by your server before sending the response, so unfortunately not.
you can write this code in separate jsp page and include that jsp in all your pages.

Comment: Thanxx for your suggestion, I'll apply this.